# Check In Encrypted Procedures to VSS

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-sourcesafe, sql-server-2008, encryption

I am trying to cut-over stored procedures from SSMS to Visual Source Safe.
My question is this.
I have a few procedures which are encrypted with the `WITH ENCRYPTION` keyword.
Now if I am to check-in these procedures to VSS, will I still be able to check it out considering that it is encrypted?

What I know is that I cannot view the script directly through SSMS unless I decrypt the procedure. But I don't know about checking it in through VSS.

Comment: What exactly are you checking in? A source file?

Comment: Yes, I am checking in a .sql file stored procedure.

Comment: You do realise that VSS is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text `WITH ENCRYPTION` in a plain text file (eg, a `.sql` source file) does not magically make the file unreadable.

That will work fine.